# Dash app does not run on the http://127.0.0.1:8050/

Tags: plotly-dash

I have the following code for a dash app that uploads a csv with points and displays them in a map.

I am not sure if the code is correct and the app can be run, because when I try to run the app although the message I get is that the app is running in http://127.0.0.1:8050/ when I open a browser nothing happens.

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import base64
import datetime
import io
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dash import dash_table



external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files')
        ]),
        style={
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '60px',
            'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px',
            'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'margin': '10px'
        },
        # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
        multiple=True
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-data-upload'),
])

def parse_contents(contents, filename, date):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    try:
        if 'csv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
            df = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
        elif 'xls' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div([
            dcc.Graph(
                fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scattergeo(lon=df['Lon_84'],lat=df['Lat_84'],text=df['text'],mode='markers',marker_color=df['Temp_C_ML'])),
            ),  
            
             ])                     
      
@app.callback(Output('output-data-upload', 'children'),
              Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
              State('upload-data', 'filename'),
              State('upload-data', 'last_modified'))
def update_output(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates):
    if list_of_contents is not None:
        children = [
            parse_contents(c, n, d) for c, n, d in
            zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates)]
        return children
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Which IDE are you using to run code? If it was Jupyter Notebook, you should change to `debug=False`

Comment: Just tried your suggestions and it works. Thank you. I think Dash works better in Spyder than Jupyter notebook